# How to pick the table name in the select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to pick the table name in the select query? Below query returns around 200 tables. Out of 200 tables, roughly around 10 - 15 tables has the id = 0.

How to pick the table name in the select query?

Expected Result : Table Name, Count in the Select Query

```
    select  'select count(*) from' + ' ' + name + ' ' + 'where id = 0 group by 
 id having count(*) > 1 ' from sysobjects 
    where id in ( select id from syscolumns where name = 'Id' )
    and xtype = 'U'
    and name like 'T%'
    order by id
```

Comment: I would urge you to read this question and ask yourself if you would have any idea what you are asking based only on the details in your question. As posted this just makes no sense at all.

Comment: So you are doing this with dynamic sql and you don't know how to add the table name to your query? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Select tables in your schema got multiple rows where the Id columm value is zero. Is that?

Comment: I would recommend using sys.objects and sys.columns instead of the deprecated versions you are using. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syscolumns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables which have rows with `Id = 0`:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
select  @SQL = STUFF((SELECT ' union all select ''' + name + ''' AS TableName, count(*) from' + ' ' + name + ' ' + 'where id = 0 group by id having count(*) > 1' from sysobjects 
    where id in ( select id from syscolumns where name = 'Id' )
    and xtype = 'U'
    and name like 'T%'
    order by id
    FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    ,1
    ,11
    ,''
)

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the query in your question makes any sense for you, is it what you want?

```
    select  'select ''' + name + ''' AS Name, count(*) from ' + name + ' where id = 0 group by 
 id having count(*) > 1' from sysobjects 
    where id in ( select id from syscolumns where name = 'Id' )
    and xtype = 'U'
    and name like 'T%'
    order by id
```

Comment: What i am expecting is .. Imagine we have a table name as Employee.  Employee, 10

Comment: That works.. very helpful.. now further customizing this query .. is there a way to return only the select query which has records..  right now, i am getting the select query with and without records

Comment: @goofyui you would have to execute the dynamic sql to know.

Comment: @SeanLange, can i get some help on dynamic sql ?

Comment: I don't get it, you have a query that builds up a sql string but you don't know how to execute it? What were planning on doing with this string?

Comment: If you want to get tables with records, can you try to follow instructions there then? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-stats-properties-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017